# Android ArrayAdapter equivalent in Gtk?

Tags: android, c, gtk, gtk3, gnome

Displaying an array of objects in a GtkTreeView can be quite complicated, as you have to copy the values from the array into a GtkListStore and then write a lot of code to keep them synchronized. *(Or store the objects in the ListStore directly, which is then clumsy to access)*

Android has an elegant solution to this issue by having an [Adapter class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter), which is a wrapper for an array where all you have to define is a function that gets the *n*th item of the array and fills a widget or row with it. (Along with methods for handling the *n*th row being clicked, etc.)

Does a similar class exist in Gtk? (or a 3rd party addition)
How would one go about implementing a class like this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a class in Gtk. If you want to implement it, you will need to rewrite (or subclass) `GtkListStore` ([source](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/master/gtk/gtkliststore.c)), or to be more precise, write a new class which realizes `GtkTreeModel` interface. Plus you should somehow notify your model when the array changes.